# ExcelPackage reads empty rows in C#

Tags: c#, excelpackage

I want ro read my excel file. It reads file in a nice way. It gets the row count using this code

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(filename)
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1]; 
int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
```

It works fine.But my issue is initially in my excel file it has 10 row count. After that i delete some rows for example i deleted 5 rows.Now this code return to only 5.But it doesn't produce the count 5. It also takes the count of empty rows in excel file. How to overcome this issue

Comment: are you deleting the rows or just clearing them?

Comment: i just select the rows and delete them

Comment: You need to right click on selected row and delete them using the menu option

Comment: yeah its working if we delete using menu option. instead of how we can manage using the code wise. if it is possible?

Comment: You to read upto the last non empty row for that

Comment: Can u explain how to read that?

Comment: Read all the columns of each row and check if they are empty. If all columns for a row are empty dont read any more rows.